# Not a valid command: it when executing sbt it

Tags: scala, sbt

I followed the steps for adding integration tests found at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#integration-tests.

However, when I run `sbt it`, see the following:

```
$ sbt it
[info] Loading project definition from myproj/project
[info] Set current project to myproj (in build file:myproj/)
[error] Not a valid command: it
[error] Not a valid project ID: it
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: it
[error] it
[error]   ^
```

`sbt test` works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's described in [Integration Tests](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#integration-tests) is about how to add a new configuration, namely `it`. There are many configurations available, e.g. `Compile`, `Test`, `Runtime`, `Docs`, `Pom` - you can find the default ones as `vals` in the [sbt.Configuration](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala#L32) object.

The official documentation of SBT in [Selecting the configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings.html#selecting-the-configuration) and [Scoping by configuration axis](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#scoping-by-configuration-axis) should explain why you calling `sbt it` would require a command or a task with the `it` name which as it turned out was not the case.

The `it` configuration binds tasks that you may have used in the other configurations like `test` be reconfigured so the integration tests are in `it` directory (rather than in their default one - `src/test`).

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch of googling, I realized the problem was that integration tests aren't quite the same as tests.  To run integration tests, the configuration is slightly different:

`sbt it:test`

When I do that, everything works fine.

Comment: The sbt terminology is that `it` is a "configuration".